# JQuery - get value of data attribute of element in selector, not in attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am always looking for a shorter and faster way of making jQuery selections, and I wondered if there is a shorter way to select the value of the data attribute of a given element. Now I have this

```
const phoneCode = $('#loginCountryCodeInput').attr('data-phone-code');
```

to get the value of this data attribute

```
<input id="loginCountryCodeInput" data-phone-code="+1">
```

Is there a shorter selector, something like this?

```
const phoneCode = $('#loginCountryCodeInput[data-phone-code]');
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get custom `data-*` attribute value.

```
$('#loginCountryCodeInput').data('phone-code');
```

---

**FYI :** There is no way to get the value by a selector, which generates a jQuery object.

---

There are some difference between the methods : [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: Nice but the question is to achieve it by selectors :)

Comment: @Marco : there is no way to get it's value, simply using selector :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have `.data()` function for that

```
$("#controlid").data("phone-code");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It's almost like the one you wrote, but you need to use `$("#id-of-element[property='value']")`.
E.g.: `$("#loginCountryCodeInput[data-phone-code='+1']")`

Source documentation: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

try this. there any other answer available. take which one best suite for you.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-phone-code="+1"]');
$('a[data-phone-code=+1]');
```